# JavaFx: custom event either doesn't get fired or not listened to

Tags: java, javafx, events, event-handling

Minimal code example:

```java
public class HelloApplication extends Application implements EventHandler<HelloApplication.MyEvent> {

    public class MyEvent extends Event {
        public static final EventType TYPE = new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "MyType");
        public MyEvent() {
            super(TYPE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MyEvent myEvent) {
        System.out.println("Event handled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 640, 480));
        Button button1 = new Button("Click");
        button1.setOnAction(event -> {
            button1.fireEvent(new MyEvent());
            System.out.println("Event fired!");
        });
        root.setTop(button1);
        Button button2 = new Button("Clack");
        button2.addEventHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, this);
        root.setBottom(button2);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I get "Event fired!" in my console but not "Event handled!".

It works when I add the event listener to button1. Am I missing something obvious? Is it not possible to fire an event on A and listen to it on B?

Comment: Create and post a [mre]

Comment: It seems as though you are firing the event on an object that is different to the one on which you are observing the event, but it's difficult to tell from the code snippets you've shown. Perhaps off-topic, but the code design here just doesn't seem to be well-designed to work with JavaFX. Why is there so much inheritance?

Comment: Working on minimal example. Yes, the object firing is different from the object listening. Is that bad? I'm a JavaFX beginner.

Comment: there is the minimal example

Comment: *"Is it not possible to fire an event on A and listen to it on B?"*. Handlers for events registered with objects are only invoked if the object on which they are registered fires an event. Otherwise a handler for an "OK" button (for example) would be invoked when any button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. You can add that as answer.

Comment: *"The object firing is different to the object listening."* That's actually not the point. The point is that the object firing the event is different to *the one on which the handler is registered*. Here the object firing is `button1`. The object listening is the current `HelloApplication` instance. This is fine. The handler is not invoked because it is registered on `button2`, which never fires the event.

Comment: One final note: this is probably not the right approach to whatever it is you're trying to do. I've never needed to create custom events. There are use cases for them, but as a beginner you're highly unlikely to come across them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code

```
button2.addEventHandler(MyEvent.TYPE, this);
```

registers the current `HelloApplication` instance (`this`) as an event handler with `button2`. This means that whenever `button2` fires an event with event type `MyEvent.TYPE`, then `this.handle(...)` will be invoked.

However, in the code you posted, `button2` never fires such an event. The only time that event is fired is via the code

```
button1.fireEvent(new MyEvent());
```

which of course causes `button1` to fire the event, not `button2`.